# powershell - split csv into multiple csv by column

Tags: powershell

I have .csv like that:

[image]

but many more lines of course.. (sorry I have added it like picture because text was not able to be formatted correctly)

and I would like to have 4 .csv files like which contains every column separatelly so in x.csv, I will only have data from first column. in y.csv I will have only data from second column (they are separated by ";"

so far I have this code but I'm not able to even loop through columns (looping through rows works..)

```
$dataaa = Import-Csv ".\input.csv" -Delimiter ";" | Group ID | %{
    $ID=".\out.csv" -f $_.Name
    $_.Group | export-csv "$CurDir\$ID" -NoType
}

$a=0
echo "$a"

$Results = foreach( $Column in $dataaa ){
$a=$a+1
echo "$a" #echo number of column
#select first column and export into x.csv - have NO idea how to
}

echo "$a"
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, which allows for any potential column names you may have:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path input.csv -Delimiter ';'
$properties = (Get-Member -InputObject $csv[0] -MemberType Properties).Name
foreach ($property in $properties) {
    $csv | Select-Object @{n=$property;e={$_.$property}} |
        Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$property.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
}
```

[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) will need a calculated property here because your property names have [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7) characters. The use of the `-LiteralPath` switch may be necessary on some commands because of the wildcard characters as well.

Comment: oh man.. what you have write I would be never able to write - THANK YOU 100000000 times! now I can study that code to understand it :) also I was trying some other code and was thinking that it doesn't work because of file name contains [] but it works in your code so coool.. btw. just currious for the future - original csv has only clean text/numbers and ";" symbols but new csv has every line in "" symbols like "0.2454" and not just 0.2454 - is there any special way to have clean lines without "" symbols or that is just a way how ps works? but thanks a lot man anyway!

Comment: I got it ;) need to manually remove characters + a little play due to the special file names `$file = ".\PositionX ``[mm``].csv" 
Get-Content $file | Foreach {$_ -replace '"', ""}  | Set-Content ".\oxxx.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

Its should be straight forward:

1.) Import the data with import-csv into a variable e.g. $tmp (dont forget to set the  delimter correctly

2.) Select the property with $tmp | Select-Object -Property Position x...

3.) Export the selected data with export csv (and maybe the parameter notypeinformation)